# C++ - Capitalize the first Character for each word in the given string

Tags: c++

I have a char pointer , then i convert it into string format. So i would like to capitalize the first character of each word in this string, I wrote the code below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void transform(char *s);
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *str = new char[255];
    strcpy(str, "jimmy catter");
    string s;
    s+=str; //convert char to string
    std::cout<<s<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ')
        {
            if (islower(s[i+1])==1)
            {
                s[i+1] = toupper(s[i+1]);
            }       
        }

    }
    std::cout<<s<<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to the output shoule be "Jimmy Catter" , but the result i got is still in the lower format. Could you please help look with this ?

Comment: Use `string s = "jimmy catter"` instead of all these "conversions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First thing to note here is that `islower` returns non zero(>0) number if argument is lowercase instead of 1.
2. Second you are trying to capitalize char by checking if char before it was `whitespace`. Nothing wrong with this approach but it won't work on first character so you can do it by adding an extra line before the loop. So with some tweaking it works fine now:

   ```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    // void transform(char *s);
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        string s = "jimmy catter ";

        /* 
        char *str = new char[255];
        strcpy(str, "jimmy catter");
        string s;
        s+=str; //convert char to string 
        */

        std::cout<<s<<endl;
        s[0]=toupper(s[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; ++i)
        {   
            if (s[i] == ' ')
            {
                if (islower(s[i+1])>=1)
                {
                    s[i+1] = toupper(s[i+1]);
                }       
            }

        }
        std::cout<<s<<endl; 
        return 0;
    }
   ```

Comment: `if (islower(s[i+1])` is a potential access violation.  Look at Kai O's response below.

Comment: @paulsm4 True , never thought of that, so i changed the code such that it won't iterate through last element so even if we use s[i+1] there won't be any access violation.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, there are two things here:

1. `islower()` should be treated as if it returns a `bool`, even if it says it returns an `int`. This is because for a `bool`, the actual value is `false` if 0 and `true` if any value other than 0. This means that if you wanted to still compare to a numerical value you would say `islower(s[i]) != 0` since 1 is not the only valid internal value for `true`.
2. For the first character (J), there isn't a space before it. So, what we can do is check the current character is the first character OR if the previous character is space. Basically, instead of checking the current character and changing the next character, we check the previous character (or if it's the first character) and then change the current character.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void transform(char *s);
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *str = new char[255];
    strcpy(str, "jimmy catter");
    string s;
    s+=str; //convert char to string
    std::cout<<s<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        if (i == 0 || s[i - 1] == ' ') {
            if (islower(s[i])) {
                s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
            }       
        }

    }
    std::cout<<s<<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mentioned two problems ... but you also fixed a third: the potential out-of-bounds error.  By checking `s[i - 1]`, and updating `s[i])`.  Good job :)

Answer (score -1):

You may use ASCII notations because they are quite clear to understand and execute in such programs.
I modified your code a little bit in the loop part and it gives correct output. Have a look at it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
{
        if(!i&&97<=s[i]<=122)           //handles border condition where first letter is small case
        {
            s[i] = s[i]-32;
    }
    
     if ((i!=s.length-1)&&s[i] == ' ')  //prevents invalid output where last character is a space   
     {
          if (97<=s[i+1]<=122)      //checks if letter after space is small case
          {
            s[i+1] = s[i+1]-32;
          }       
     }

}
std::cout<<s<<endl; 
return 0;
```

}